# Basic enquiry on swapping and tuple assignment

Tags: pointers, go

If I want to swap the values of two variables in `go`, I would do

```
func swap(xPtr, yPtr *int) {
    dummy := *xPtr                                                           
    *xPtr = *yPtr                                                            
    *yPtr = *xPtr                                                            
}
```

However, the cleanest solution is `*xPtr, *yPtr = *yPtr, *xPtr`. Why this has different effect than computing

```
*xPtr = *yPtr                                                            
*yPtr = *xPtr
```

In other words, from pure syntax I understand that if  `*xPtr=1`, `*yPtr=2`,
then both must be modified to `2`, and not to `2, 1` as `*xPtr, *yPtr = *yPtr, *xPtr` actually does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, to swap simply write:

```
*xPtr, *yPtr = *yPtr, *xPtr
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)
>
> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued
>   operation to a list of variables. There are two forms. In the first,
>   the right hand operand is a single multi-valued expression such as a
>   function call, a channel or map operation, or a type assertion. The
>   number of operands on the left hand side must match the number of
>   values.
>
> In the second form, the number of operands on the left must equal the
>   number of expressions on the right, each of which must be
>   single-valued, and the nth expression on the right is assigned to the
>   nth operand on the left:
>
> ```
> one, two, three = '一', '二', '三'
> ```
>
> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of index
>   expressions and pointer indirections (including implicit pointer
>   indirections in selectors) on the left and the expressions on the
>   right are all evaluated in the usual order. Second, the assignments
>   are carried out in left-to-right order.

---

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of pointer
>   indirections on the left and the expressions on the right are all
>   evaluated in the usual order. Second, the assignments are carried out
>   in left-to-right order.

For example, swapping to and fro:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    xPtr, yPtr := new(int), new(int)
    *xPtr, *yPtr = 1, 2
    fmt.Println(*xPtr, *yPtr)

    // Swap - idiomatic Go
    *xPtr, *yPtr = *yPtr, *xPtr
    fmt.Println(*xPtr, *yPtr)

    // is equivalent to

    // RHS - evaluate
    ty := *yPtr
    tx := *xPtr
    // LHS - assign
    *xPtr = ty
    *yPtr = tx
    fmt.Println(*xPtr, *yPtr)

    // is equivalent to

    // Optimized
    t := *xPtr
    *xPtr = *yPtr
    *yPtr = t
    fmt.Println(*xPtr, *yPtr)

    // is not equivalent to

    // Error: No swap
    *xPtr = *yPtr
    *yPtr = *xPtr
    fmt.Println(*xPtr, *yPtr)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Ph4Dsc_jsJJ

Output:

```
1 2
2 1
1 2
2 1
1 1
```